# No me reconoce la librería java.sql.connection en java NetBeans

Tags: java, sql-server

Hice una conexión de una entre una base de datos en SQL Server Express 2014 y Java NetBeans 8.2 para hacer la interfaz. Logre hacer bien la conexión pero al querer usar una biblioteca en Java no me la reconoce quería ocupar el comando class.forName y no me lo reconoce [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal compañero, tu error está en que cuando verificas que el driver exista mediante el nombre de la clase, la palabra reservada ***Class*** la tienes en minúscula al igual que en el **TRY** ***ClassNotFoundException***, adicional puedes ir a la siguiente ruta:

https://parapasarso.blogcindario.com/2016/11/00035-netbeans-java-8-y-sql-server-express-2014.html

Este enlace te muestra paso a paso con imágenes a preparar la conexión en tu gestor de base de datos y en el IDE.

o también este otro enlace:

http://conectarjavasqlserver.blogspot.com/

Esta contiene una conexión básica por si quieres probar y adicional un video de explicación.

Disculpa que no te ponga el código acá, pero con esto puedes investigar y verificar tu error.

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: mejora tu respuesta por favor, agrega lo relevante de los enlaces

Comment: Listo @shadow, gracias por la observación, saludos.

Comment: La respuesta en si, es que las palabras reservadas están en minúsculas, si cambia eso, el código le funciona, adicional, que en un solo try puede meter la conexión y manejar las diferentes excepciones, pero si gustas, mejor quito los enlaces ya que tiende a dar una idea equívoca de lo que deseo compartir, tu me indicas míster

Comment: Y le pongo el código de como debe quedar mejor